# Make Recycler View show rows from bottom

Tags: android

I saw somewhere method to make `RecyclerView` show `ViewHolders` from bottom to top. Now, i can't find it anywhere (after half of hour going through `RecyclerView`, `RecyclerAdapter`, `LayoutManager`...).

Comment: But when i have one ViewHolder, i want it to appear on the bottom and so. Also i wouldn't be able to scroll to top and just add more rows (like making endless list and loading more data when user pull up).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Is it `LinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)` you are looking for?

**Edit**

Turns out `LinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true)` does the trick. Either way, the reader may want to try each of the methods and the combination of both to get the needed effect.

Comment: I'm dumb. I was looking under RecyclerView.LayoutManager.

But i think that right method is  setReverseLayout(boolean ReverseLayout) also inside LinearLayoutManager. Going to check

Comment: Was going to offer it as well, but I think it's for a different thing :) I use them both at the same time in my project to make rows appear from the top, adding new on top of old ones.

Comment: ok, i got some time to test it: .setStackFromEnd(true) doesn't work, but .setReverseLayout(true) does work perfect. Anyway, I will accept your answer as correct (you might want to add .setReverseLayout in answer just for future viewers).

Comment: Set both, setReverseLayout and setStackFromEnd lets the behavior as default. Just with setReverseLayout is enaught.

Comment: The last param of the `LinearLayoutManager`constructor is `reverseLayout` when set to true seems to mess with an `ItemDecorator` that I have setup.  If i set this param to false then the `ItemDecorator` lays out the items as desired.

Comment: I can't believe something Android related that should be simple is actually simple.  Been getting used to googling, "How to do [simple task] in android?," and seeing the most popular answers be something along the lines of, "Do a balancing act on one foot, juggle 3 peaches and 8 coconuts, and jump through 9 hoops while humming the beat of 'Gangnam Style.'"

Answer (score 23):

Here is the solution in **Kotlin**

```
val llm = LinearLayoutManager(this)
llm.stackFromEnd = true     // items gravity sticks to bottom
llm.reverseLayout = false   // item list sorting (new messages start from the bottom)

rv_chat_history.layoutManager = llm
```

Or if you like the apply method:

```
recycler.apply { 
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this).apply { 
        stackFromEnd = true
        reverseLayout = false
    }
}
```

Comment: One says reverse layout false and the other says reverse layout true.

Comment: @paul_f That was an edit by others. I have rectified it. Thanks for the pointing out.

Answer (score 20):

You can achieve this task by adding two lines to the xml code.

```
app:stackFromEnd="false"
app:reverseLayout="true"
```

This will work as all chat apps.

Comment: doesn't seem to work, are there other changes required?

Comment: yes of course if you load items dynamically from service you should scroll to bottom after adding any item by add this line  `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1);`

Comment: @MostafaAnter maybe you was wrong, if we use these two fields together, mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0); will show the latest item (of chat list for example), we call this line only one times (does not call it when load more pages)

Comment: WhatsApp does not stackFromEnd and I don't think they reverse layout because they still use ListViews. They simply load the last x amount of messages per chat, and scroll to bottom. When you scroll up, they load more previous messages. In my own experience with RecyclerViews I found reversing the layout slows the rendering down quite a bit, don't ask me why

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **LinearLayoutManager** make third param (reverseLayout)  **false**

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager =
            new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution on your query:

---

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=
                new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,true);
                layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

In above code recyclerView is the id of RecyclerView and layoutManager is object of LinearLayoutManager.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was achieved by setting `stackFromEnd = true`, `reverseLayout = false` on the `LinearLayoutManager` and setting `scrollToPosition(index_of_last_element)`

```
recyclerView?.apply {
 layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context).apply {
   stackFromEnd = true
   reverseLayout = false
 }
}

recyclerView?.scrollToPosition(equations.size - 1)
```

[View Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kmo2.jpg)

Comment: you need to set `reverseLayout = true`

Comment: Thank you @KidusTekeste for suggestion and I know most of the answers on this forum have `reverseLayout = true`. However in my case setting it false worked. You can see it's working in the animation provided.

Answer (score 0):

it took me hours upon hours to fix it on my side , basically you have to

> Find the position of the message with the latest date and time before updating the adapter ,

> then update the adapter after scroll to bottom . the Scroll will be instant just like in whatsapp etc

```
 val latestMessagePosition = liveMessagesData.size - 1
                    messagesAdaptor.setData(liveMessagesData)
                    if (latestMessagePosition >= 0) {
                        recyclerViewMessages.scrollToPosition(latestMessagePosition)
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

> **This is working for me in kotlin**
>
> ```
> recyclerView?.scrollToPosition(mArrayList.size - 1)
> ```