# Can't set Recycler to start from bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get my recyclerview to start from the bottom

[Make Recycler View show rows from bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474876/make-recycler-view-show-rows-from-bottom)

According to this answer I've tried both

```
mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
mMessageRecycler.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
```

and using `reverseLayout` in XML

```
app:stackFromEnd="true"
app:reverseLayout="true"
```

However none of them is making the recyclerview start from bottom... It's still starting from top

here's my entire layout:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/challengeroom_recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/challengeroom_et_sendmessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/vertical_guideline_75percent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:stackFromEnd="true"
        app:reverseLayout="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);;
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)
mMessageRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager)
```

Comment: The first messages are being displayed from the bottom, how do I make the latest messages, start from the bottom?

Comment: reverse your arraylist which contain recylerview items. `Collections.reverse(yourArraylist)`

Comment: The correct answer should be ```layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true)```