# Is there a way to stack a CardView within a RecyclerView from the bottom instead of from the top?

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, cardview

I'm a newbie when it comes to Android coding, so please bear with me. I looked this up for quite some time before posting here, so that I don't waste your time with a question that I could have answered myself through some research.

Here's my issue: I have a `CardView` and I want the items to start popping up from the bottom instead of from the top. For example, [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTZPB.png).

I found out that you can do this via the "stackFromBottom" XML attribute in `ListViews` and `GridViews`, but it doesn't work for CardViews.
I also noticed that you can change a `ListView`'s gravity, but `CardView` doesn't seem to support that either.

So is there a simple way to populate the `CardView` in this way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest switching to using a recycler view and the use [a simple property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474876/make-recycler-view-show-rows-from-bottom) to accomplish what you need

Comment: Oh, good thing you said that, I am already using a Recycler View, but I thought the issue was within the CardView, so I didn't mention it. I will try this right away, thanks!

Comment: @javdromero This really helped me solve it, would you mind posting your reply as an answer so I can mark this as Solved? Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, also would be better if you change listview to recylcer view in your question, they are similar but no the same and i'm pretty sure this answer doesn't work for listviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said that you are using a `recycler view` you could use [a simple property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474876/make-recycler-view-show-rows-from-bottom) to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`CardView` can hold only a single item, so in this case you can have a `ViewGroup` inside the `CardView` , and add those items to the `ViewGroup`.

I'd suggest `ConstraintLayout` and constraint the first view to the bottom of the layout and next views are constraint to their bottom views so that you can fill them from the bottom.

If your list is big.. You can wrap the `ConstraintLayout` with `ScrollView` so that the items can be scrolled; or replace the entire approach by a `RecyclerView`

Comment: This is the exact answer I was going to give.