# How to load the last message in the bottom of the RecyclerView - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm doing an APP and when the user send some message, if the `ChatScreen` is empty the `RecyclerView` starts loading the `MessageBox` in  the top of the APP, as the image is showing:

[image: Actual APP RecyclerView]

I would like to know how to change to start showing the `MessageBox` in the bottom of the screen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474876/make-recycler-view-show-rows-from-bottom